# onAuthStateChanged not getting called, firebase + react native

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am trying to create an authentication flow where a user is redirected to the home page after they register. I am using react-navigation to direct the user to a registration page when they open the app and are not logged in.

On the registration page, it correctly creates a new user in firebase with createUserWithEmailAndPassword(), but onAuthStateChanged does not fire. What I want is for the user state to change causing the "Home" screen to render.

Do you know why onAuthStateChanged might not be causing app.js to rerender?

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {
  LoginScreen,
  HomeScreen,
  RegistrationScreen,
  HomePage,
} from './src/screens';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello from home screen');
    const usersRef = firestore().collection('users');
    auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        usersRef
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then(document => {
            const userData = document.data();
            setLoading(false);
            setUser(userData);
            console.log('hello from auth');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  if (loading) {
    return <></>;
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {props => <HomePage {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Register component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';
import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

export default function RegistrationScreen({navigation}) {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  };

  const onRegisterPress = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("Passwords don't match.");
      return;
    }
    auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(async response => {
        const uid = response.user.uid;
        const data = {
          id: uid,
          email,
          fullName,
        };
        const usersRef = await firestore().collection('users');
        usersRef
          .doc(uid)
          .set(data)
          .then(() => {
            navigation.navigate('Home', {additionalUserInfo: data});
          })
          .catch(error => {
            alert(error);
          });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
        <Image
          style={styles.logo}
          source={require('../../../assets/icon.png')}
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="Full Name"
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          onChangeText={text => setFullName(text)}
          value={fullName}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder="E-mail"
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}
          value={email}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}
          value={password}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
          secureTextEntry
          placeholder="Confirm Password"
          onChangeText={text => setConfirmPassword(text)}
          value={confirmPassword}
          underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          autoCapitalize="none"
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => onRegisterPress()}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Create account</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.footerView}>
          <Text style={styles.footerText}>
            Already got an account?{' '}
            <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress} style={styles.footerLink}>
              Log in
            </Text>
          </Text>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```